# Urlrewriting in web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I've just started to explore adding url rewrite rules to my web.config.

I've used 2 rules:

1) canonical url from *.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com and 2) Http to Https.

```
<rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*"/>
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
```

I've followed examples to get to this stage but would appreciate it if someone could sense check this for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look good to me on at a glance.

I would suggest testing out the rules in your local environment. Keep in mind Firefox loves to cache these so if you make changes to a rule you'll have to clear the cache.